# How can you bind an attached property to DisplayMemberPath of a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I can't seem to find the correct syntax to allow an attached property to be used as the DisplayMemberPath of a ComboBox.

The property is SelectorSwitchedControl.NameForSelector
It's in the namespace 'LocalTest' which is mapped to the XAML prefix 'local'.

Here's the code...

```
<UserControl x:Class="Playground.SelectorSwitchedControlTest.SelectorSwitchedControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:glc="clr-namespace:Playground.CommonControls"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Playground.SelectorSwitchedControlTest"
    Background="Transparent">

    <Border x:Name="MainBorder"
        BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">

        <DockPanel>

            <glc:FixedToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">

                <ComboBox x:Name="MainSelector"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Children, ElementName=MainPanel}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="(local:SelectorSwitchedControl.NameForSelector)" />

            </glc:FixedToolBar>

            <local:SelectorSwitchedControlPanel x:Name="MainPanel" />

        </DockPanel>

    </Border>

</UserControl>
```

...which for some reason gives me the exception 'Prefix 'local' does not map to a namespace.' which I'm not sure why it's saying that as if I remove the 'DisplayMemberPath' line, the '' tag renders just like it's supposed to proving the namespace is mapped.

I've also tried all of the following...

- DisplayMemberPath="local:SelectorSwitchedControl.NameForSelector"
- DisplayMemberPath="(local:SelectorSwitchedControl.NameForSelector)"
- DisplayMemberPath="SelectorSwitchedControl.NameForSelector"
- DisplayMemberPath="(SelectorSwitchedControl.NameForSelector)"
- DisplayMemberPath="LocalTest.SelectorSwitchedControl.NameForSelector"
- DisplayMemberPath="(LocalTest.SelectorSwitchedControl.NameForSelector)"

I know it's just one of those days where my mind isn't working and I'm missing something simple, but it's driving me crazy!  So what's the proper syntax?

Comment: I don't see the word `{Binding}` anywhere in your code.

Comment: This is a strange one... personally, I would have gone for `DisplayMemberPath="(local:SelectorSwitchedControl.NameForSelector)"`. However, after a quick search, I couldn't find anything useful on `Binding` and `DisplayMemberPath`. I checked MSDN and can confirm that the `DisplayMemberPath` property *is* a `DependencyProperty` that uses the `BindableAttribute` set to `true`.

Comment: Have you set the `DataContext="{StaticResource SomeSource}"` and the `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`?

Comment: HighCore, I tried this too... 'DisplayMemberPath="{Binding (local:SelectorSwitchedControl.NameForSelector)}"' but when I do that I get the runtime exception 'Prefix 'local' does not map to a namespace.' which it obviously does.

Answer (score 2):

DisplayMemberPath - path to the display **string property** for each item. Set it to "NameForSelector", not to "{Binding NameForSelector}".

```
 <DockPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="MainSelector" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DisplayMemberPath="NameForSelector" />
 </DockPanel>

 public class SelectorSwitchedControl
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string NameForSelector{ get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: But it's not 'NameForSelector'... it's 'SelectorSwitchedControl.NameForSelector'.  I don't think the internal reflection will find it without the fully-qualified path. (I also agree about Binding.  That was in response to HighCore's answer, which I didn't agree with.)

Comment: Actually in Children collection all items should have property SelectorSwitchedControl.NameForSelector. Do not use "local:" for set DisplayMemberPath. When set ItemsSource then you can see help popup with correct properties name. I checked for my code all work fine.

Comment: Actually, not sure how I missed this before, but your code doesn't use an attached property.  You're using a standard CLR property, which is an entirely different beast altogether so this isn't an applicable answer.

Comment: Ok, show me what it's SelectorSwitchedControl and SelectorSwitchedControlPanel
 Yes my properties aren't attached property, but my code It's only sample how use DisplayMemberPath. Or explain me more.

Comment: It's not a question of using DisplayMemberPath.  It's a question of using an AttachedProperty with DisplayMemberPath.  It would be too much to write here to explain what I'm referring to.  Just look up Attached Properties in MSDN and you'll see what we're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just not possible to use an attached property in `DisplayMemberPath` with regular controls. The reason is that the property path you are using refers to an XML namespace declared in your XAML. Normally when you use the attached property syntax there is a parser context available when the XAML/BAML reader is creating the objects and this context supplies the namespace information. However `DisplayMemberPath` is just a string and does not capture this context, so this context is not available to supply the namespace information at the point where your property path is actually used to create a binding. From my reading of code in `PresentationFramework.dll`, you *might* be able to supply the context through the target object (the one to which your property is attached) by having it implement `IServiceProvider` and return a suitable `IXamlTypeResolver` (relevant code starts from `PropertyPath.GetTypeFromName`).

As a cheaper alternative, consider a template or template selector instead of `DisplayMemberPath`. If you want to use the default lookup mechanisms, try something along the lines of

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ContextPresenter 
      Content="{Binding (local:SelectorSwitchedControl.NameForSelector)}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: That was actually the first approach we went with, but a ComboBox's ItemTemplate doesn't work for the main selection area.  To do that you end up having to completely replace the template for the ComboBox which seems like overkill.  But if that's how we have to go, that's how we have to go!  If no one gives a better answer, you'll get the vote.

Comment: I see. If your combo box `IsReadOnly` and your items are of a known, specific type, you can try putting a data template like the above with an appropriate `DataType` into the window resources.

Answer (score 0):

The correct value is

```
DisplayMemberPath="(local:SelectorSwitchedControl.NameForSelector)"
```

If that is not working then I would use Snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to make sure that the value is getting set correctly.

Here is the simplest working example

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="MainWindow_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Name="cb" DisplayMemberPath="(local:MainWindow.TestValue)" />
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
public static string GetTestValue(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (string)element.GetValue(TestValueProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTestValue(DependencyObject element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(TestValueProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestValueProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TestValue", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock tb = default(TextBlock);


        for (int i = 10; i <= 15; i++)
        {
            tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = "Text for " + i;
            tb.SetValue(TestValueProperty, "Property For " + i);
            this.cb.Items.Add(tb);
        }
    }
```